# API поиска по организации не показывает организацию

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Не могу разобраться в методе поиска организации по долготе и широте.

Есть запрос, я забиваю координаты организации
https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?apikey=3apikey&text=62.542371,73.843706&lang=ru_RU&results=25

Мне выдает кучу информации по региону, но ни в какую не хочет показывать ту точку на карте, которая по этим координатам - Куст № 3Б Когалымского месторождения

Если же делаю запрос [https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?apikey=apikey&text=Куст](https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?apikey=apikey&text=%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82) № 3Б Когалымского месторождения&lang=ru_RU

То он мне выдает координаты, из первого запроса - 62.542371,73.843706

Подскажите что делаю не так.

Конечная цель:
По координатам найти ближайшую точку на карте. В моем случае это Куст № 3Б Когалымского месторождения

Спасибо за содействие

Answer (score 0):

Скорей всего вас интересует данный метод и апи геокодирирования:
https://yandex.ru/dev/geocode/doc/ru/response

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: я его так же пробовал. Он, к сожалению, тоже не выдает желанный Куст :(

Answer (score 0):

Указывайте координаты в параметре ll, а в поле text пропишите «Промышленная инфраструктура». Так будет найдена ближайшая к центру поиска интересующая вас организация из этой категории. Пример запроса:

```
https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?text=Промышленная инфраструктура&type=biz&lang=ru_RU&ll=73.844105,62.542379&apikey={{apikey}}
```